# Exterior derivative on loop space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-operators, loop-spaces

### Notations:

Let $X$ be a manifold, and denote by $LX := C^\infty(S^1,X)$ its loop space. For a loop $\gamma \in LX$ we can think at the tangent space of $LX$ at the point $\gamma$ as the space of loops that are 'arbitrarily closed' to $\gamma$. This motivates the following definition

$$T_{\gamma}LX := \Gamma(S^1, \gamma^*TX),$$

where $\Gamma(S^1, \gamma^*TX)$ denote the space of section of the pullback bundle
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    \gamma^*TX @>>> TX\\
    @V  V V @VV  V\\
    S^1 @>>\gamma> X.
\end{CD}
This is the description of the tangent bundle $TLX \to LX$ of the loop space of $X$. By definition a $k$-differential form on $LX$ is a section of the $k^{th}$ exterior power of $TLX^*$, the cotangent bundle.
$$\Omega^k(LX):= \Gamma(LX, \Lambda^kTLX^*).$$

### Question:

How is the exterior differential $d$ defined for differential forms on loop space? 
\begin{CD}
\Omega^k(LX) @>d>> \Omega^{k+1}(LX)
\end{CD}

Comment: The loop space is an infinite-dimensional manifold. Hence, the exterior differential is defined by the same formula as in the finite-dimensional setting. See for example these notes: https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/wockel/data/monastir.pdf

Comment: Minor detail but do you mean $\Omega^k(LX): = \Gamma(LX, \bigwedge^k TLX^\vee)$ (that is, $k$th exterior power of the *co*tangent bundle)

Comment: yes, of course. Thank you.

Comment: As Tobias remarks, the real question here is "How do vector fields on $LX$ (according to the given definition) act as derivations on smooth functions on $LX$?" And this is again as in the finite dimensional setting: consider a curve in $LX$ starting at $\gamma$ and with tangent vector at $t=0$ given by $v_\gamma$...

Comment: There's a chapter in Kreigel and Michor's book: the convenient setting of global analysis, where they discuss all the different ways of defining forms. I recommend reading it.